# Can you download a specific Block from an Azure Block Blob?

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is it possible to download a specific block from an Azure Block Blob if you know the Block Id?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you absolutely can, here's an example of how to download the first block:

```cs
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

CloudBlobClient serviceClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("containerName");

var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blobName");

var blocklist = await blockBlob.DownloadBlockListAsync();

var firstBlock = blocklist.First();

var memStream = new MemoryStream();

await blockBlob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(memStream, 0, firstBlock.Length);

string contents;

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memStream))
{
    contents = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

You will need a couple of packages from nuget:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob
```

Comment: The equivalent API using the newer storage client is [BlockBlobClient.GetBlockListAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blockblobclient.getblocklistasync?view=azure-dotnet)

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) for getting started with Azure Blob Storage quickly. And the Azure Storage SDK is a wrapper of [Blob Service REST API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/). From the official tutorial about [Blob Service REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee691974.aspx), we couldn't find anything about downloading the specific block via the Block Id. In addition, you could use [Get Blob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179440.aspx) to download the bytes of your blob in the specified range by specifying the offset and the length of data to download from your blob.